# How to use useState to display a different language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, localization, use-state

I'm trying to do a function using useState to change the languages of my website. However, I'm having an issue thinking about the logic of how can it be done since I'm newbie.

1st question:
How can I use the function "handleLanguage" to change the menu language when I click in `<li>`.

2nd question:
Which would be the best way to change the whole language website by clicking on the option? Because as I see, now if I click, will change only one component.

**Code:**

```
const languages = {
  en: {
    about: "about",
    project: "project",
    contact: "contact",
    slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
    button: "Learn more",
  },
  ptbr: {
    about: "sobre",
    project: "projetos",
    contact: "contatos",
    slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
    button: "Learn more",
  },
  jp: {
    about: "nihon",
    project: "nihon",
    contact: "nihon",
    slogan: "nihon",
    button: "nihon",
  },
  ru: {
    about: "руский",
    project: "руский",
    contact: "руский",
    slogan: "руский",
    button: "руский",
  },
};

const RightNav = ({ open }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("en");

  const handleLanguage = (e) => {
    setText("ptbr");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Ul open={open}>
        <li>{languages.en.about}</li>
        <li>{languages.en.project}</li>
        <li>{languages.en.contact}</li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={English} alt="EN" />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Japanese} alt="JP" />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Russian} alt="RU" />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Portuguese} alt="PT-BR" onClick={handleLanguage} />
        </li>
      </Ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use the function "handleLanguage" to change the menu
> language when I click in?

I would convert `handleLanguage` into a curried function to enclose a language value when attaching as a callback to select a language.

```
const RightNav = ({ open }) => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");

  const handleLanguage = language => event => {
    setLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Ul open={open}>
        <li>{languages[language].about}</li>
        <li>{languages[language].project}</li>
        <li>{languages[language].contact}</li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={English} alt="EN" onClick={handleLanguage('en')} />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Japanese} alt="JP" onClick={handleLanguage('jp')} />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Russian} alt="RU" onClick={handleLanguage('ru')} />
        </li>
        <li className="image">
          <img src={Portuguese} alt="PT-BR" onClick={handleLanguage('ptbr')} />
        </li>
      </Ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

> Which would be the best way to change the whole language website by
> clicking on the option? Because as I see, now if I click, will change
> only one component.

For this you will likely need to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor so all the components that need to either access the current language strings, or to update the current language.

Using the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) may actually be a better use case for you so you won't need to explicitly pass all the strings data down to each component as props.

This is a similar approach many localization libraries use, i.e. they have a sting provider and expose a function to take a string id and the current set language return the correct localized text. [React-intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/) is one such popular localization library.

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I understand the logic also. I will read the docs that you sent also to improve the code.